# PNG image displays half transparent in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have subclassed an `UITextField`, so that there is an icon next to the text field, here is the code:

```
iconView = [UIImageView new];
self.textField = [UITextField new];
self.textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
self.textField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
self.layer.borderColor = TEXTFIELD_BORDER_COLOR;
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//iconView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[self.textField setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[iconView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[self addSubview:iconView];
[self addSubview:self.textField];
[self setUpConstraints];
```

When I set an image, which doesn't have any transparency inside, everything works fine, but when I set with transparency I get faint, half visible image.
Here are two examples of image, first displays fine, second is barely visible:

[image: Userimage]

[image: LockImage]

Comment: check if alpha value of `iconView` is one or set it to one before adding `iconView.alpha = 1` in view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your image.

In the first image (the person one), the gray colored area is opaque. And in the second image (the lock), the gray colored area is almost transparent (opacity is at 31%).